# Enable all range selector's options in stock highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

In range-selector, I have many options to select from (in reality) and in given demo, I initially load `last 2 hours` data.

In this scenario, `last 1 hour` option is enabled but **other options are disabled**.

I really don't know what is wrong. The requirement is to load `last 2 hour` data first and then from dropdown, you can select other options (eg. last 6 hours) and accordingly data will be loaded.

**How to enable other options in range-selector ?**

I tried setting

```
minRange:1
```

but I have no clue how to fix it.

**DEMO** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2eyktg?file=index.js,chartOptions.js,mock-data%2Fi.js

---

**Updates:**

I tried using

```
 allButtonsEnabled: true,
```

It enables all options but when I click on `3 hours, 6 hours` options, it doesn't make any BE call. I believed that it should automatically call **afterSetExtremes** functions with **min** & **max** value, fetch data from BE and update the chart **but it doesn't happen**.

**DEMO** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jsxchg?file=index.js,chartOptions.js,backend.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

a) Set `min` property for an x-axis in a navigator:

```
  navigator: {
    xAxis: {
      min: currentTimestamp - 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 6 hours
    }, 
    // adaptToUpdatedData: false,
    ...
  }
```

**Live example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-m38td3?file=index.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.xAxis

---

b) Enable `rangeSelector.allButtonsEnabled` property and use `afterBtnClick` Highcharts event. The event `afterSetExtremes` is not called if the extremes are the same as the current one (they are because of initial min and max restriction).

```
chart: {
  zoomType: 'x',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      Highcharts.addEvent(
        this.rangeSelector,
        'afterBtnClick',
        function() {
          const button = this.buttonOptions[this.selected];
          const chart = this.chart;

          afterSetExtremes({
            target: {
              chart
            },
            min: chart.xAxis[0].dataMax - button._range,
            max: chart.xAxis[0].dataMax
          });
        });
    }
  }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tuzuuz?file=chartOptions.js,index.js,index.html

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting different approaches. Thanks a lot...